# calculate and display difference between 2 dates before submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to find find a way to calculate the difference between 2 dates, and display the result before I submit the form.  This will be similar to the check in - check out drop downs in the yellow/ orange box in http://www.booking.com/ where on selecting the dates the number of nights is immediately displayed.

HTML version of code as displayed in JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chri_chri/xy2gpa02/2/

Code used to generate the drop down date selectors

```
  <?php 
  // displays days with leading 0s
  $options = array();

   for ($i=1; $i<32; $i++) {
   $theday = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,0,$i,2000));
   $sel = ($i == date('d') ? 'selected="selected"' : '');
   $options[] = "<option value= \"{$theday}\" {$sel}>{$theday}
   </option>";
  }

  $options_list = join("\r\n", $options);
  echo "<div class='select' id='date'><select class=\"short-input\" name=\"day_from\">{$options_list}</select></div>";    
  ?>

  <?php
  $options = array();

  for ($i = 1; $i<13; $i++) {
  $themonth = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$i,2, 2000));
  $month = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$i,2,2000));
  $sel =($i == date('n') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
  $options[] = "<option value=\"{$month}\" {$sel}>{$themonth}
  </option>";
  }
  $options_list = join("\r\n", $options);
  echo "<div class='select' id='month'><select class=\"short-input\" name=\"month_from\" size=\"1\">{$options_list}</select></div>";
  ?>

  <?php 
  /* build selection list for the year */
  $today = time(); // stores today's date
  $startYr = date("Y", $today); // get the year from $today
 echo "<div class='select' id='year'>
                            <select class='short-input' name='year_from'>\n";
 for ($year=$startYr;$year<=$startYr+10;$year++)
 {
    echo " <option value= $year";
    if ($startYr == $year)
    {
    echo "";
 }
 echo " > $year</option>\n";
 }
 echo "</select>\n</div>\n";
 ?>
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using? If it's >= 5.2 you could consider using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects

Comment: If local, open terminal/cmd and enter `php -v`

Comment: If hosted: 1) If commercial, search for your host plan docs for specifications 2) If private/managed, ask the system admin.

Comment: theres the trick create a php file with `phpinfo()` and host that file

Comment: That part is solved :) thanks. :) its version 5.4.3 something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options, use java-script or submit form to php file and process the form. 
jsfiddle working example http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/3b5fyzjL/32/

// the script

```
function stayCost() {
  var dayFrom = $('.day-from').val();
  var monthFrom = $('.month-from').val();
  var yearFrom = $('.year-from').val();
  var dateFrom = Date.parse(monthFrom + ' ' + dayFrom + ' ' + yearFrom);
  var dayTo = $('.day-to').val();
  var monthTo = $('.month-to').val();
  var yearTo = $('.year-to').val();
  var dateTo = Date.parse(monthTo + ' ' + dayTo + ' ' + yearTo);
  var dateDifference = dateTo - dateFrom;
  var diffInDays = Math.ceil(dateDifference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  $('.days').text(diffInDays);
  $('.cost').text(diffInDays * 40);
}
stayCost();
$('.day-to').change(function () {
  stayCost();
});
```

Comment: I would like to use javascript as I need to know the value before submitting the form.

Comment: You would need to get the day, month and year from each date and create a date string, date1 = valueofday+'-'+valueofmonth+'-'+valudeofyear; date2 = valueofday+'-'+valueofmonth+'-'+valudeofyear

Comment: Would value of month, day and year be equal to name = 'x' in select? example if the select name is day_from then valueofday = day_from?

Comment: Then I assume I can echo the result using getElementById?

Comment: see my updated answer, if you want to display how many days or night you would need to convert the timestamp.

Comment: Have tried the code you posted, replacing your values with mine, however nothing is displayed.

Comment: see code example [http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/3b5fyzjL/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/3b5fyzjL/4/)

Comment: chekc out the full demo on jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/3b5fyzjL/19/](http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/3b5fyzjL/19/)

Comment: Is there a reason it doesn't work when I select different dates?

Comment: the date change did not trigger anything, i did wrap the code in a function that gets triggered when you change the date to [http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/3b5fyzjL/32/](http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/3b5fyzjL/32/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87442/discussion-between-mdamia-and-christa).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87515/discussion-between-christa-and-mdamia).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) - did a minor change (updates on month-to change rather than day-to change to increase user friendliness.